# Is there a way to make a material ui's linear progress bar appear like a seekbar for a music app?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Using material-ui's linear progress bar as a seekbar and so far I am able to wire it with the audio duration and updating the current play location.
But I want the bar to be clickable like a seekbar in any media website and play the audio/video at that particular timestamp.

Here is my code of the linear progress bar:

```
<LinearProgress
          className="top"
          variant="determinate"
          value={(this.state.currentTime * 100) / this.state.duration}
        />
```

Comment: Use slider component instead. https://material-ui.com/components/slider/

Comment: Was going to tell the same as @demkovych, just use a slider and style the sphere to only show on hover, see this [example](https://material-ui.com/components/slider/#customized-sliders) from them

Comment: Thanks to @demkovych. Does the job pretty well.

Comment: Just one more question. The slider value attribute is wired with state changes and it works pretty well when the audio is playing but I can't seem to slide the sphere. What am I doing wrong?
```          <Slider
            className="top"
            value={(this.state.currentTime * 100) / this.state.duration}
            // onChange={handleChange}
            aria-labelledby="continuous-slider"
          />```

Answer (score 0):

```
<span style={{width: your wudth}}>
  <Slider style={{width: videoRef.current?.clientWidth ? videoRef.current?.clientWidth-176.5 : 0}}
          min={0}
          max={duration}
          value={currentTime}
          onChange={handleProgressChange}
          aria-labelledby="continuous-slider"
  />
</span>

const handleProgressChange = (e: any, value: any) => {
  videoRef.current!.currentTime = value;
  e.preventDefault();
}
```